# Uniform Convergence of tanh(x)

Tags: real-analysis

Just a quick question,

does $f_n(x)=\tanh(nx)$ converge uniformly?

Comment: On which domain?

Comment: If a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly, they converge to a continuous function. What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n$? See [the uniform convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_continuity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\tanh$ is an odd function, we will assume $x>0$

$$\tanh(nx)=\frac{1-e^{-2nx}}{1+e^{-2nx}}$$

thus

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\tanh(nx)=1$

if $x=0,  f_n(0)=0$.

all the functions $f_n$ are continuous at $\mathbb R$.

the  pointwise limit function is not continuous at $0$, thus the convergence is not uniform at $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I did not know that a discontinuous pointwise limit function implied it is not uniform

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Which function does $f_n$ converge pointwise to? Is it continuous?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $\tanh(nx)\rightarrow \operatorname{sign}(x)$ pointwise as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Now, use the fact that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous for a locally compact space (such as $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: I got the same pointwise limit function, it's obviously not continuous at 0 but does that mean that it doesn't converge uniformly? Is there a way to set epsilon st the uniformly convergence definition does not hold?